# Mongoose findOne Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

*login.js*

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        req.session.userId = user._id;        
        res.render('dashboard', { user: user });
    });
});
```

---

*dashboards.hbs*

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>{{user.email}}</h3>
</div>
```

---

What I am trying to achieve here is to send the user object to handlebars and print `user.email` property. 
The issue is that it only works when I hard code the `req.body.email` to `User.findOne({ email: 'mesam' })`. Then it would render dashboard and be print `user.email` which is mesam.

Why isn't it working when `req.body.email` comes from a form ?

Comment: What does your `req.body` look like?  Do you see `email` listed there?  Maybe you don't have `name="email"` on your email input.  It would be helpful to have the code for your form in the question.

Comment: Need more information to understand what you mean by 'not working'..

Comment: @Maverick976 I did not have the name="email" it is fixed now! Thanks :D